# Retrieving Values From Gravity Forms for Custom User Meta

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm a little frustrated with Gravity Forms at the moment.
Here's my setup:
I have a custom registration form created with **WPEverest's User Registration** plugin. This plugin creates a custom user registration form that seamlessly integrates with WooCommerce, and also saves custom fields to the USER, rather than in a separate table.

I'm trying to use **Gravity Forms** to allow users to update field's created with WPEverest's Registration Plugin(which at this point is just some custom user meta fields), but I'm having a hell of a time getting the field values.

My biggest issue is that I can't for the life of me figure out what the heck value I'm supposed to pass through `get_post_custom_values();`.

The code below is what I have so far. This is supposed to pass a value to the user meta field upon form submit, and it does work... but only if I set the value as a manually created variable. It will not work if I try to pull the data from Gravity Forms.

```
$gravity_form_id = '10'; // Gravity Forms ID
add_action("gform_after_submission_$gravity_form_id", "gravity_post_submission", 10, 2);
function gravity_post_submission ($entry, $form){

    $post_id = $entry["post_id"]; 
    
    //trying to get values from gravity form
    $values = get_post_custom_values("field_name???", $post_id);

    //updating user meta
    update_post_meta($current_user->ID, 'user_registration_body_type', $values);

}
```

For reference, the form object I'm using is a RADIO type with ID 10, and a parameter name of body_type (I'm using this name as a means to pre-populate the form fields).

Here's how the form field renders:

```
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_radio">
  <ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_14_10">
    <li class="gchoice_14_10_0">
      <input name="input_10" type="radio" value="apple" id="choice_14_10_0">
      <label for="choice_14_10_0" id="label_14_10_0">Apple</label>
    </li>
    <li class="gchoice_14_10_1">
      <input name="input_10" type="radio" value="full-bust" id="choice_14_10_1">
      <label for="choice_14_10_1" id="label_14_10_1">Full Bust</label>
    </li>
    <li class="gchoice_14_10_2">
      <input name="input_10" type="radio" value="hourglass" checked="checked" id="choice_14_10_2">
      <label for="choice_14_10_2" id="label_14_10_2">Hourglass</label>
    </li>
    <li class="gchoice_14_10_3">
      <input name="input_10" type="radio" value="pear" id="choice_14_10_3">
      <label for="choice_14_10_3" id="label_14_10_3">Pear</label>
    </li>
    <li class="gchoice_14_10_4">
      <input name="input_10" type="radio" value="straight" id="choice_14_10_4">
     <label for="choice_14_10_4" id="label_14_10_4">Straight</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

TL;DR - What am I supposed to replace `form_field???` with in order to retrieve the form field value? What ID or Name am I supposed to use? (ex: input_10, input_14_10, body_type ?) I'll be trying to do the same thing with checkboxes later, but it seemed easier to start with a radio button since it only returns one value.

Or am I approaching this problem all wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

- Add form id to the gform_after_submission_. It looks like you are using form id 14 but this code are for form id 10.
- use rgar to specify the field id (10)
- use update_user_meta
- Get the current user ID (This means that you must be logged in before subitting the form.

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_10", "gravity_post_submission", 10, 2);
function gravity_post_submission ($entry, $form){
    
    //Gets field id 10
    $values = rgar( $entry, '10' );
    
    //updating user meta
    update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_registration_body_type', $values );
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative answer. I know my original question was asking about the ID number, but after a lot of experimentation, I learned that there's no need for this code at all (which addresses the second part of my question, "am I approaching this issue wrong?").

Gravity forms actually has the in-built ability to write data to custom fields (even for users through a registration process), but does not have the ability to create custom fields itself. I finally found this information in the [Gravity Forms Documentation](https://docs.gravityforms.com/post-custom/).

Doing so is very simple, but you have to have the PRO version.
To do this:

1. Create a Custom Field for the post type (or in the example's case, the user meta) - you can use something like Advanced Custom Fields for this, or custom code in your functions.php file
2. Use the **Post Custom Field** form item from the Advanced form item options in the form builder
3. From the **Post Custom Field's Custom Field Name** section, select "Existing" and then the name of the field you created from the dropdown.

Gravity Forms handles the rest.

So while Fredrik's answer is correct, if you are able to create a custom field, you can just use Gravity Forms existing functionality and avoid adding extra code altogether.

Hope this helps someone as the gravity_post_submission hook is... finicky at best - at least in my experience.